# Passing parameters to httpsCallable cloud function from Flutter code

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-functions

Using this code snippet to call `httpsCallable` cloud function on firebase:

```dart
@override
  Future<InitializePickupRequestCommandResult> initialize(
    ClientEntity client,
    PositionEntity location,
    PositionEntity destination, {
    required bool isVehicleEmpty,
  }) async {
    final data = InitializePickupRequestCommand.from(
      client,
      location,
      destination,
      isVehicleEmpty: isVehicleEmpty,
    ).toJson();

    final name = describeEnum(CloudFunctionNames.initializePickupRequest);

    final initializePickupRequest = backend.httpsCallable(name);

    final result = await initializePickupRequest.call(data);

    return InitializePickupRequestCommandResult.from(
      result.data as Map<String, dynamic>,
    );
  }
```

`data` object holds all required data for the CF to perform the operation, it is of type `Map<String, dynamic>`.

```dart
 Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "clientId": clientId,
        "clientLat": clientLat,
        "clientLng": clientLng,
        "vehicleType": vehicleType,
        "isVehicleEmpty": isVehicleEmpty,
        "location": {
          "lat": clientLat,
          "lng": clientLng,
        },
        "destination": {
          "placeId": destination.id,
          "zip": destination.zip,
          "city": destination.city,
          "searchString": destination.searchString,
          "lat": destination.lat,
          "lng": destination.lng,
        },
      };
```

#### Problem

every time when trying to call the CF, it throws this exception:

> _AssertionError ('package:cloud_functions/src/https_callable.dart': Failed assertion: line 33 pos 12: '_debugIsValidParameterType(parameters)': is not true.)

#### What i tried

using these as params:

- `data as Map<String, dynamic>`
- `{...data}`
- `<String, dynamic>{...data}`

Tried `{"dummy": "data"}` as a param and the CF was executed normally. don't know why!

So **how parameters should be passed to https callable cloud function**?

Comment: I am not sure but maybe the last commas are the problem when there is nothing after them, like `"lng": clientLng,`, `"lng": destination.lng,` and the last `},`. Try removing them. It's ok in Flutter but maybe it means an invalid JSON.

Comment: Another thing: try `jsonEncode(data)` before submitting.

Comment: @PeterKoltai your last comment led to the answer below.

Comment: @joe_izn Great!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem was in `toJson()` specifically in `"vehicleType": vehicleType,` because the value is an **enum property** and that what was throwing the invalid parameters exception.

Now using`"vehicleType": vehicleType.index,`

Comment: Same thing happened to me. It was a parameter that was a `Duration`. Basically, if you get this, check all your parameters.