# Why is my call to a Firebase Cloud Function returning an invalid parm error?

Tags: android, flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-functions

Getting this error:

> Unhandled Exception: 'package:cloud_functions/src/https_callable.dart': Failed assertion: line 34 pos 12: '_debugIsValidParameterType(parameters)': is not true.

I originally thought it might have been because my `createdTimestamp` parm was a `Map<String, String>` so I simplified it to just be a simple `String`, but this is still giving the same error:

```
await FirebaseFunctions.instance.httpsCallable('callGroupRTDBSetup').call({
      groupID: groupID,
      adminUID: adminUID,
      adminUsername: adminUsername,
      createdTimestamp: '1690519017833',
});
```

**Edit:** This is getting weirder and weirder. The `call` function in `https_callable.dart` has this line right at the beginning: `assert(_debugIsValidParameterType(parameters));`. This function is defined below.

```
/// Whether a given call parameter is a valid type.
bool _debugIsValidParameterType(dynamic parameter, [bool isRoot = true]) {
  if (parameter is List) {
    for (final element in parameter) {
      if (!_debugIsValidParameterType(element, false)) {
        return false;
      }
    }
    return true;
  }

  if (parameter is Map) {
    for (final key in parameter.keys) {
      if (key is! String) {
        return false;
      }
    }
    for (final value in parameter.values) {
      if (!_debugIsValidParameterType(value, false)) {
        return false;
      }
    }
    return true;
  }

  return parameter == null ||
      parameter is String ||
      parameter is num ||
      parameter is bool;
}
```

If I take this same function and run it independently using a copy of it with a different name, it returns true, meaning that my `createdTimestamp` parameter is valid. ***However***, if I try to use the same parameter in the actual call, the Run tab tells me that `'_debugIsValidParameterType(parameters)': is not true`. I'm using the same function used to `assert` and it runs fine independently but it fails when it is run via `call()`.

```
Map<String, String> createdTimestamp = getRTDBTimestamp();

final result = testDebugIsValidParameterType(createdTimestamp); //RETURNS TRUE

final callResult = await FirebaseFunctions.instance.httpsCallable('callGroupRTDBSetup').call({ //ERROR HERE: '_debugIsValidParameterType(parameters)': is not true
  createdTimestamp: createdTimestamp,
});
```

Comment: Have you seen https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68785472/passing-parameters-to-httpscallable-cloud-function-from-flutter-code

Comment: @RenaudTarnec yes I found that question when I initially googled, but it didn't help.

Comment: The answer in that question is actually what drove me to simplify the last parameter in my call from a `Map<String, String>` to a `String`, but I'm still getting the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out.

**Before:**

```
final callResult = await FirebaseFunctions.instance.httpsCallable('callGroupRTDBSetup').call({
  createdTimestamp: createdTimestamp,
});
```

**After:**

```
Map<String, String> parms = {
  'createdTimestamp': '1234567',
};

final callResult = await FirebaseFunctions.instance.httpsCallable('callGroupRTDBSetup').call(parms);
```

The problem was that I was using `call` with the brackets, meaning that I was already inside of a `Map<String, String>`, so passing in another `Map<String, String>` with the `createdTimestamp` parm failed the assertion.